# ARKit - Rotating a moving SCNNode to face the camera

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I am using this function to animate a rotation of a SCNNode:

```
   let rotateNode = SCNAction.rotateTo(x: 0.0, y: CGFloat((headingAngle )), z: 0.0, duration: TimeInterval(1.1), usesShortestUnitArc: true)


    node.runAction(rotateNode)
```

It works really well for different directions except for when I need to rotate it towards the **user** (or the camera for that matter).

My question is how to direct the SCNNode **to move towards the user**/camera and how to calculate the ***headingAngle*** in order to rotate the SCNNode to face the user/camera when it is moving.

I perform the moving by using

```
           let impulseVector = SCNVector3(
            x: 0.0 ,
            y: 5.0,
            z: 0.0
        )

    node.physicsBody?.applyForce(impulseVector, at: positionOnNodeToApplyForceTo, asImpulse: true) // propell
```

And I am aware that the headingAngle needs to be calculated using `atan2` function, but for some reason I do not manage to properly direct the SCNNode **to move towards the camera nor to rotate and face the camera.**